# Identity string stream in C++

Tags: c++, tokenize, stringstream

Is it possible to have a string stream which has this behavior ?

```
std::istringstream stringstream("hello world");
std::string output;
stringstream >> output;
assert(output == "hello world");
```

Use case :

```
template <typename T>
T as(void) {
    T t;
    std::istringstream stringstream(this->m_str);
    stringstream >> t;
    return t;
}
```

It will not work if T is std::string. I could make a specialization, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, because it 'tokenizes' the input. Have you tried to set the input string as `"\"hello world\""`. I believe it would come out as `"hello word"` instead of `hello world`.

Comment: You'd need to derive from one of stream classes and re-implement extraction operator for string to do that. But you can do `output = stringstream.str();` instead.

Comment: Just to understand: is there any particular reason why you don't want to use `stringstream.str()` ?

Comment: @jrok: If I have a function that takes a `std::istream`, from which I read one *word* (`in >> str;`) and that wrote multiple words into `str` I would be surprised. While your overriden `operator<<` has the same interface, at the language level, as that of the base, you are redefining the semantics, violating the contract of the class. Note that the *interface* of the class is not just the signature of the functions, but also the expected behavior.

Comment: @ereOn Updated with my use case

Comment: @David I never said it's a good idea :)

Comment: @NisonMaël: You **should** add an specialization in this case. That is the simple way of getting the expected semantics and it will also be more efficient (why go through the work of the two conversions to end up with the same result?)

Comment: @NisonMaël Please explain what "doesn't work" mean regarding your snippet. The code will behave the same way for any type. If you have a member string such as "123  456", you'll get the first "word" out of it using operator>>. Either as a string "123" or as an int 123 or something else... Assuming of course, you're doing formatted input.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, as the `operator>>` overload that takes a `std::string` will only read up to and not including the first whitespace, so the call will just get `"hello"`.

Comment: But isn't there a way to turn off this behavior ?

Comment: @NisonMaël: you should really explain what you are trying to achieve, rather than how to fix your approach that might not be appropriate. If you create your own `mystream` that has that behavior and you pass it to other code to read with `operator>>` the code there will expect the call to return one word, but your overloaded operator would return multiple words, which might end breaking other code somewhere else.

Comment: @NisonMaël: Any reason why you don't want to specialize?

Comment: Not especially. I like being as generic as possible, I'm not fond of specializations, even if it's the way to go sometimes. I'm gonna use it, however I'm curious about @Torsten answer, is it possible to use ctype facet to inhibe spliting ?

Comment: @NisonMaël: So you are willing to add more code as long as it is not an *specialization* when the simple solution is *specializing*? What I would do is create a private implementation template and a free function and then dispatch (all member): `template <typename T> void as( T& t ) { /*impl as in question*/ } void as( std::string& s) { s = m_str; } template <typename T> T as() { T r; as(r); return r; }` (Note that I don't quite like specializations for functions, but you can in most cases add overloads to avoid it.